# symfony, can't I access to entity on another controller?

Tags: symfony

`DefaultController.php`

```php
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->get ( 'email' )) {            
        $email = $request->get ( 'email' );
        $em = $this->getDoctrine ();
        $mst_USERS = $em->getRepository ( 'AppBundle:mst_USERS' );
        $mst_USERS->findAll ();

        return $this->render ( 'default/main.html.twig', array (
                'email' => $email,
                'mst_USERS' => $mst_USERS 
        ) );
    }
```

`main.html.twig`

```
{% block styleSheet %}
<style>
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div id="container">
    THIS IS

    {{email}}
    <ul>
        {% for mst_USERS in mst_USERS %}
        <li>{{mst_USERS.email}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block styleSheet %}
<style>
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to use AppBundle:mst_USERS entity for DefaultController but It doesn't work at all.

It was working on another controller, named mst_USERSController.php
Can't I using it on another controller or is there something wrong?

Comment: You can use any entity in any controller. In your code you made mistake to get email use {% for mst_USER in mst_USERS %}       <li>{{mst_USER.email}}</li>{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at home

```
{% for user in mst_USERS %}
<li>{{user.email}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And in the controller add

```
return $this->render ( 'default/main.html.twig', array (
    'email' => $email,
    'mst_USERS' => $mst_USERS->findAll()
));
```

Comment: Might want to add:  
$mst_USERS = $em->getRepository ( 'AppBundle:mst_USERS' )->findAll(); as well.